# Displaying only first row from datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, localdb

I have two tables Invoice, Invoice2

Invoice has many columns like invoiceno,itemcode, itemrate etc

while Invoice2 has only one column invoiceno that has same value as in Invoice table

I want to display rows from database that have same invoiceno in both tables
it is doing that

Now what i want to do is retrieve only those rows from Invoice table that belong only to the 'first' invoiceno in Invoice2 table

Iam creating buttons for first, next , previous , last

so when i click first it should display rows that belong to the first invoicno that is common in both tables

im using datagridview to display data

windows forms , c#

```
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select invoices.itemcode, invoices.itemname,invoices.quantity,invoices.itemrate from invoices, invoice where invoices.invoiceno= invoice.invoiceno ", con);

        adpt.Fill(ds, "invoices");


        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow row = new DataRow();
            int i = 0;
            row.Cells[0].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["itemcode"].ToString();
            row.Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["itemname"].ToString();
            row.Cells[2].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["itemrate"].ToString();
        }

      dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["invoices"];
```

Comment: Have you some code for it?

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: iam unable to move between records in database . i want to display the rows from first table in datagridview that have invoiceno same as invoiceno in second table

Comment: so when i click first ..rows belonging to invoiceno "qwe12" should be displayed only

Comment: What did you tried so far ? Show us the code you have produce and we will try to help you. Besides i think you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and welcome to SO

Comment: sorry iam a little lost or maybe too much

Comment: Do you really want to write to `row.Cells[0]` three times, or did you mean to increment it to `1` and then `2`?

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois
i just want the correct syntax for getting all rows from fist table that belong to one invoiceno then when i press next button it should get rows for the second invoiceno

Comment: @RickDavin
row.cells[0] then row.cells[1] ..ive edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform an order by in your query to have sorted resultset,Then

```
DataView view = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
DataTable distinctInvoiceNumbers = view.ToTable(true, "invoiceno");
//clear datagrid rows here
 DataTable dt=new Datatable();
 dt = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
 int index=0;// zero if first is clicked, increase index for each next button click
 foreach(datarow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
   if(distinctInvoiceNumbers.Rows[0][index].ToString()==dr[0].ToString())
    {
      dt.ImportRow(dr);//add matching rows to datatable
    }
  }
  datagridview1.DataSource=dt;
```

Comment: it gives error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Ambiguous column name 'invoiceno'.

Comment: your query for joining tables should be like SELECT i1.invoiceno, 
       i1.itemcode, 
       i1.itemname, 
       i1.quantity, 
       i1.itemrate 
FROM   invoice i1 
       JOIN invoice2 i2 
         ON i1.invoiceno = i2.invoiceno 
ORDER  BY i1.invoiceno;

Comment: yes i edited that and added order by statement like u said .. it is still giving this error

Comment: @Vanessa I just checked on SQLfiddle, Its working.[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3cc737/3)

Comment: now it is giving error
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Column 'invoiceno' does not belong to underlying table 'invoices'.

although this column is in that table

Comment: try debugging with simple select query instead of join and view the datatable column names in visualizer, does it contain invoiceno column?

Comment: okay but now it is giving just this in datagridview first cell

System.Data.DataRow

instead of displaying data from table

Comment: @Vanessa Edited answer.

Comment: okay..ive done the changes ..but now it displays only one row instead of all rows that belong to that particular invoiceno..I want it to display all rows from table that belong to that same invoice no

Comment: Check input values in your tables once, Might be there is only one match foor the particular value.I  executed the code and found that it adds all the row to datagridview.

Comment: even if I enter exact same data in all columns belonging to same invoiceno, it still only displays the first row from invoices table
the if-statement in foreach loop exectues only 1 time

Comment: @Vanessa Just add ToString() to the variables in the if condition as edited in the code.

Comment: Thankyou soo much for the help .it works atlast !
can u please help me how to increase the index whenever the Next button is clicked?

Comment: @Vanessa Sure, But it would be more appropriate if you post it as a separate question as it would help other users if they search for the same kind of issue.